# How to provide friend function to a specific member function in a class with multiple member functions so that the specified member function

Tags: c++, class, declaration, friend-function

How to provide friend function to a specific member function in a class with multiple member functions so that the specified member function can only access private data of another class while other member function should not.

Comment: Just declare the membre function as a friend function within another class definition.

Comment: You can do this (as Vlad from Moscow demonstrates below) but it's bad style. A class is the basic unit of modular programming in C++. If one member function of a class has access, the whole class ought to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void f() const;
};

class B
{
public:
    B( int i = 0 ) : i( i ) {}

    friend void A::f() const;

private:
    int i;
};

void A::f() const
{
    B b( 10 );

    std::cout << "b.i = " << b.i << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    A().f();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
b.i = 10
```